# Replace the related model collection array with a new formatted one

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, model

I have an `order`, `lamp` and `lamp_order` table. Currently I fetch the Orders and it's Lamp relationships. I also fetch the Images that are related to the Lamps like this:

```
 $orders = Order::with('lamps.image')->get();
```

I count how many times a Lamp is related to the Order grouped by room like this:

```
$lamps = DB::table('lamp_order')
            ->where('order_id', $order->id)
            ->select('lamp_id', 'order_id', 'room', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('room')
            ->groupBy('lamp_id')
            ->get();
```

I now want to add the count and room name to the Lamp collection so I did this:

```
$foundLamp = Lamp::find($lamp->lamp_id);
            $collection = collect($foundLamp);
            $collection->put('count', $lamp->total);
            $collection->put('room', $lamp->room);
            $formattedLampsArray[] = $collection;
```

How can I replace the related `Lamp` collection from the `Order` with the new one I just formatted? This is the whole function:

```
  public function index()
    {
        // Fetch orders with their relationships relationships. 
        $orders = Order::with('lamps.image')->get();

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $lamps = DB::table('lamp_order')
                ->where('order_id', $order->id)
                ->select('lamp_id', 'order_id', 'room', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->groupBy('room')
                ->groupBy('lamp_id')
                ->get();

            $formattedLampsArray = [];

            foreach ($lamps as $lamp) {
                $foundLamp = Lamp::find($lamp->lamp_id);
                $collection = collect($foundLamp);
                $collection->put('count', $lamp->total);
                $collection->put('room', $lamp->room);
                $formattedLampsArray[] = $collection;
            }
        }

        return response()->json([
            'orders' => $orders
        ], 200);
    }
```

Basically I now would like to add the `$formattedLampsArray` to each `$order`. So I can easily get the new formatted related lamps for each order in the front-end. Does anyone know how I can 'replace' the lamps with the new ones?

The result would preferably look like this:

```
'id' => 1,
'name' => 'John Doe'
'email' => 'johndoe@gmail.com'
'notes' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
'created_at' => '2020-04-02 12:32:30' 
'updated_at' => '2020-04-02 12:32:30'
'lamps_count' => 20
'grouped_lamps' => [
  [
   'id' => 9
   'name' => 'Lamp 1'
   'fitting' => 'E14'
   'shape' => 'Candle'
   'room' => 'Hall'
   'count' => '5'
  ],
  [
   'id' => 9
   'name' => 'Lamp 1'
   'fitting' => 'E14'
   'shape' => 'Candle'
   'room' => 'Kitchen'
   'count' => '5'
  ],
  [
   'id' => 11
   'name' => 'Lamp 2'
   'fitting' => 'E27'
   'shape' => 'Pear'
   'room' => 'Livingroom'
   'count' => '5'
  ],
  [
   'id' => 12
   'name' => 'Lamp 3'
   'fitting' => 'E27'
   'shape' => 'Pear'
   'room' => 'Sleepingroom'
   'count' => '5'
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The answer of AH.Pooladvand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990665/7603806) helped me in the right direction but it didn't match my requirements. That's why I still gave it the +50 bounty award. A friend of me told me that I should query the pivot table directly. I combined both answers into this piece of code.

> **I need to mention that it isn't efficient yet, when I have the full answer I will post it here. But I want to post this to help others in
>   the meantime.**

```
   public function index()
    {

        // Get all Orders and count the amount of related Lamps.
        $orders = Order::withCount('lamps')
            ->with('lamps.image') // Also fetch related Image of the Lamp
            ->get()
            ->map(static function (Order $order) {
                // For each lamp count how many times it occurs per room.
                $order->lamps->each(static function (Lamp $lamp) {
                    $countedLamps = DB::table('lamp_order')
                        ->select(DB::raw('*, count(*) as count_lamps'))
                        ->groupBy('lamp_id', 'room')
                        ->get();

                    foreach ($countedLamps as $countedLamp) {
                        // If lamp_id and room are the same then add the count and room to the Lamp. 
                        if ($countedLamp->lamp_id == $lamp['id'] && $countedLamp->room == $lamp['pivot']['room']) {
                            $lamp->count = $countedLamp->count_lamps;
                            $lamp->room = $countedLamp->room;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Remove duplicate Lamps an create an new attribute in the collection array.
                $collection = collect($order->lamps);
                $order->ordered_lamps = $collection->unique()->values()->all();
                // Make unordered Lamps array hidden.
                $order->makeHidden('lamps');
                return $order;
            });

        return response()->json([
            'orders' => $orders,
        ], 200);
    }
```

I fetch all the Orders,immediately count the amount of Lamps in that Order and get the related Image of that Lamp. For each Order I count the lamps per `room` and `lamp_id`. For each of this `$groupedLamp` I do a dirty check to add the count and room variable to the `lamp` object itself. Then in the end I remove the duplicates from the `lamp` array, make it hidden and create an `order_lamps` variable. Any improvements are welcome. I will edit this answer when it is optimized.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you looking for
There is a `withCount()` method that does `->select('lamp_id', 'order_id', 'room', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))` job for you
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Note that because `->lamps` property is actually a relation we can't mutate it so we make it hidden and make a new property named `grouped_lamps`

```php
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::withCount('lamps')
        ->with('lamps.image')
        ->get()->map(static function (Order $order) {
            $order->lamps->each(static function (Lamp $lamp) {
                $lamp->room = $lamp['pivot']['room'];
            });

            return $order;
        })->each(function (Order $order) {
            $order->grouped_lamps = $order->lamps->groupBy(['room', 'id']);
            $order->makeHidden('lamps');

            return $order;
        });

    return response()->json([
        'orders' => $orders,
    ], 200);
}
```

**Edit**

I'm not certain if this is what you looking for but here we go

First we need to fetch that extra `room` column with our relation so make sure that in your `Order` model you add `->withPivot('room')` like so

```php
public function lamps()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Lamp::class, 'lamp_order', 'lamp_id', 'order_id')
        ->withPivot('room');
}
```

And here is the code, we no longer need to have `grouped_lamps`

```php
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::withCount('lamps')
        ->with('lamps.image')
        ->get()->map(function (Order $order) {
            $order->lamps->each(static function (Lamp $lamp) use ($order) {
                $lamp->room = $lamp['pivot']['room'];
                $lamp->count = $order->lamps_count;
            });

            return $order;
        });

    return response()->json([
        'orders' => $orders,
    ], 200);
}
```

Hope it helps

**Final Edit**
Ok by reviewing my code I found out that I did an honest mistake

the lamps relation `foreign_key` and `local_key` placements were wrong this is the correct form

```php
public function lamps()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Lamp::class, 'lamp_order', 'order_id', 'lamp_id')
        ->withPivot('room');
}
```

And here is the new version of the code
**Notice that If you are fine with previous format you don't need to use below code**

```php
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::withCount('lamps')
        ->with('lamps.image')
        ->get()
        ->map(static function (Order $order) {
            $order->lamps->each(static function (Lamp $lamp) {
                $lamp->room = $lamp['pivot']['room'];
            });

            return $order;
        })->each(function (Order $order) {
            $groupedLamps = $order->lamps->groupBy('room');
            $order->lamps->each(function (Lamp $lamp) use ($groupedLamps) {
                $lamp->count = $groupedLamps[$lamp->room]->count();
            });
        });

    return response()->json([
        'orders' => $orders,
    ], 200);
}
```

And you will get result like this

```php
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "ut fugit facilis",
            "lamps_count": 5, // Total lamps owned by this order
            "lamps": [
                {
                    "title": "ab sunt nostrum",
                    "room": "kitchen",
                    "count": 3, // Total number of kitchen lamps of order_id 1
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 1,
                        "lamp_id": 1,
                        "room": "kitchen"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "omnis dicta rerum",
                    "room": "hall",
                    "count": 2, // Total number of hall lamps of order_id 1
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 1,
                        "lamp_id": 2,
                        "room": "hall"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "eligendi deserunt et",
                    "room": "hall",
                    "count": 2, // Total number of hall lamps of order_id 1
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 1,
                        "lamp_id": 3,
                        "room": "hall"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "modi ad ea",
                    "room": "kitchen",
                    "count": 3, // Total number of kitchen lamps of order_id 1
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 1,
                        "lamp_id": 4,
                        "room": "kitchen"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "eos neque consequatur",
                    "room": "kitchen",
                    "count": 3, // Total number of kitchen lamps of order_id 1
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 1,
                        "lamp_id": 5,
                        "room": "kitchen"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "sapiente velit quas",
            "lamps_count": 2,
            "lamps": [
                {
                    "title": "eligendi deserunt et",
                    "room": "kitchen",
                    "count": 2,
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 2,
                        "lamp_id": 3,
                        "room": "kitchen"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "modi ad ea",
                    "room": "kitchen",
                    "count": 2,
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 2,
                        "lamp_id": 4,
                        "room": "kitchen"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "itaque sint voluptas",
            "lamps_count": 4,
            "lamps": [
                {
                    "title": "omnis dicta rerum",
                    "room": "kitchen",
                    "count": 1,
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 3,
                        "lamp_id": 2,
                        "room": "kitchen"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "eligendi deserunt et",
                    "room": "living_room",
                    "count": 1,
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 3,
                        "lamp_id": 3,
                        "room": "living_room"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "modi ad ea",
                    "room": "hall",
                    "count": 2,
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 3,
                        "lamp_id": 4,
                        "room": "hall"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "title": "eos neque consequatur",
                    "room": "hall",
                    "count": 2,
                    "pivot": {
                        "order_id": 3,
                        "lamp_id": 5,
                        "room": "hall"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: At first thanks for your answer, this is serious almost what I am looking for. The difficult part is that the grouped lamps are now displayed in my Vue.js front-end like this: `grouped_lamps: { Kitchen: {[...]}, Livingroom: {[...]}` which makes it difficult to iterate over as I want to display them in a table. In this table I want to show which room the lamp is in. Is it possible to add all the lamps in the grouped_lamps object, add the room and count of those lamps, and remove the duplicates. So I just get one of each lamp per room and show the count of it?

Comment: @Baspa Can you give me a dataset example?

Comment: Yes, do you want a PHP dataset example?

Comment: Maybe it is easier that I send you the relevant part of the database? It is a dummy database anyways. I don't know what would be a good way to get the data from the database and convert it to a readable PHP array

Comment: What is blurry to me is that what exactly do you want inside of lamps relation...

Comment: I updated my question with an example of how the data should preferably look like

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: It seems like the answer doesn't work yet, because in the database the Order has 10 Lamps but the lamp_count returns 2.

Comment: @Baspa updated my answer, look at the Final Edit section

Comment: The answer is almost working, the `lamps_count` count is now correct. But the count of each lamp should be how many time the lamp with that ID occurs in the room and not the count of all the lamps of that room. I'll give you some bonus bounty when this is done

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless you have a rooms table

Comment: If I create a rooms table, then how can I query it in such a way that for each lamp it counts how many time it occurs in that room?

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand Thanks for providing additional information to your post by using the [edit] functionality. But please don't pollute your post with `EDIT:` or `UPDATE:` sections. [For future readers, posts need to be standalone, without any history. These sites are not forums, but intend to be libraries of canonical, high-quality, questions and answers. Future readers are not helped by seeing all kind of history.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/316262)